# Container for Sets of Integers

Tags: c++, c++11, set

I implemented an unordered_set like container for storing small sets of unsigned integers. It uses a trivial hash table for lookups and an unordered array for quickly iterating over small sets.

I'm looking for suggestions on best practices and correctness.

```
#pragma once
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <bitset>

// T - Type of integer.
// N - Number of integers in the set from 0 to N-1
template<typename T,T N> class integer_set
{
private:
  static constexpr T NOT_IN_SET = ~static_cast<T>(0);
  static const T MIN_SIZE_TO_SEARCH_INDEX;
public:
  class iterator
  {
  public:
    iterator(const iterator& it) = default;
    iterator& operator=(const iterator& it) = default;
    iterator();
    iterator(const T* element);
    bool operator==(const iterator& it) const;
    bool operator!=(const iterator& it) const;
    bool operator<(const iterator& it) const;
    bool operator>(const iterator& it) const;
    bool operator<=(const iterator& it) const;
    bool operator>=(const iterator& it) const;
    T operator*() const;
    T operator[](T i) const;
    iterator& operator++();
    iterator operator++(int);
    iterator& operator--();
    iterator operator--(int);
    iterator operator+(T i) const;
    iterator operator-(T i) const;
    iterator& operator+=(T i);
    iterator& operator-=(T i);
  private:
    const T* m_element;
  };
public:
  // The following are undefined if the set is empty:
  //   front()
  //   back()
  //   operator[]()
  //   min()
  //   max()
  //   random()
  integer_set();
  integer_set(const integer_set& set);
  integer_set& operator=(const integer_set& set);
  bool operator==(const integer_set& set) const;
  bool operator!=(const integer_set& set) const;
  bool operator<=(const integer_set& set) const;
  bool operator>=(const integer_set& set) const;
  bool operator<(const integer_set& set) const;
  bool operator>(const integer_set& set) const;
  T front() const;
  T back() const;
  iterator begin() const;
  iterator end() const;
  iterator find(T v) const;
  T operator[](T i) const;
  T min() const;
  T max() const;
  template<class URNG> T random(URNG& gen) const;
  T size() const;
  bool empty() const;
  bool contains(T v) const;
  void clear();
  void insert(T v);
  void insert(const integer_set& set);
  void erase(T v);
  void erase(const integer_set& set);
public:
  static integer_set union_(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2);
  static integer_set intersection(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2);
  static bool union_empty(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2);
  static bool intersection_empty(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2);
private:
  // Find the smallest size where searching the index has a probability >= 0.5 of requiring fewer operations than searching the list.
  static T min_size_to_search_index();
  // Probability that we will find at least one element in the set after picking size elements at random.
  static double get_probability(T size);
private:
  // m_index[element] is the index of that element in m_list or NOT_IN_SET. For checking if element is in set.
  std::array<T,N> m_index;
  // Unordered list of elements. For iterating over set.
  std::array<T,N> m_list;
  // Number of elements in set.
  T m_size;
};

namespace std
{
  template<typename T,T N> struct hash<integer_set<T,N>>
  {
    typedef integer_set<T,N> argument_type;
    typedef std::size_t result_type;
    result_type operator()(const argument_type& set) const
    {
      std::bitset<N> bits;
      for(T v : set)
        bits.set(v);
      return std::hash<std::bitset<N>>()(bits);
    }
  };
}

template<typename T,T N> constexpr T integer_set<T,N>::NOT_IN_SET;
template<typename T,T N> const T integer_set<T,N>::MIN_SIZE_TO_SEARCH_INDEX = {min_size_to_search_index()};

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// integer_set

template<typename T,T N> integer_set<T,N>::integer_set()
  :m_size{0}
{
  m_index.fill(NOT_IN_SET);
  static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer,"T must be an integer.");
  static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value,"T must be unsigned.");
  static_assert(N<NOT_IN_SET,"N is too large.");
}

template<typename T,T N> integer_set<T,N>::integer_set(const integer_set& set)
  :m_index(set.m_index),m_size{set.m_size}
{
  for(T i=0; i<m_size; ++i)
    m_list[i] = set.m_list[i];
}

template<typename T,T N> integer_set<T,N>& integer_set<T,N>::operator=(const integer_set& set)
{
  m_size = set.m_size;
  m_index = set.m_index;
  for(T i=0; i<m_size; ++i)
    m_list[i] = set.m_list[i];
  return *this;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::operator==(const integer_set& set) const
{
  if(m_size != set.m_size)
    return false;
  for(T v : set)
  {
    if(!contains(v))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::operator!=(const integer_set& set) const
{
  return !operator==(set);
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::operator<=(const integer_set& set) const
{
  return m_index <= set.m_index;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::operator>=(const integer_set& set) const
{
  return m_index >= set.m_index;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::operator<(const integer_set& set) const
{
  return m_index < set.m_index;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::operator>(const integer_set& set) const
{
  return m_index > set.m_index;
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::front() const
{
  return m_list[0];
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::back() const
{
  return m_list[m_size-1];
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator integer_set<T,N>::begin() const
{
  return iterator(m_list.data());
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator integer_set<T,N>::end() const
{
  return iterator(m_list.data()+m_size);
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator integer_set<T,N>::find(T v) const
{
  if(m_index[v] == NOT_IN_SET)
    return end();
  else
    return iterator(m_list.data()+m_index[v]);
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::operator[](T i) const
{
  return m_list[i];
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::min() const
{
  if(m_size >= MIN_SIZE_TO_SEARCH_INDEX)
  {
    for(T i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
      if(m_index[i] != NOT_IN_SET)
        return i;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    T min = m_list[0];
    for(T i=1; i<m_size; ++i)
    {
      if(m_list[i] < min)
        min = m_list[i];
    }
    return min;
  }
  return NOT_IN_SET;
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::max() const
{
  if(m_size >= MIN_SIZE_TO_SEARCH_INDEX)
  {
    for(T i=N; i>0; --i)
    {
      if(m_index[i-1] != NOT_IN_SET)
        return i-1;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    T max = m_list[0];
    for(T i=1; i<m_size; ++i)
    {
      if(m_list[i] > max)
        max = m_list[i];
    }
    return max;
  }
  return NOT_IN_SET;
}

template<typename T,T N> template<class URNG> T integer_set<T,N>::random(URNG& gen) const
{
  return m_list[std::uniform_int_distribution<T>(0,m_size-1)(gen)];
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::size() const
{
  return m_size;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::empty() const
{
  return m_size == 0;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::contains(T v) const
{
  return m_index[v] != NOT_IN_SET;
}

template<typename T,T N> void integer_set<T,N>::clear()
{
  for(T v : *this)
    m_index[v] = NOT_IN_SET;
  m_size = 0;
}

template<typename T,T N> void integer_set<T,N>::insert(T v)
{
  if(contains(v))
    return;
  m_index[v] = m_size;
  m_list[m_size] = v;
  ++m_size;
}

template<typename T,T N> void integer_set<T,N>::insert(const integer_set& set)
{
  for(T v : set)
    insert(v);
}

template<typename T,T N> void integer_set<T,N>::erase(T v)
{
  if(!contains(v))
    return;
  --m_size;
  // If this element is not the last in the list
  // move the last element in the list to the index of v.
  if(m_index[v] != m_size)
  {
    m_list[m_index[v]] = m_list[m_size];
    m_index[m_list[m_size]] = m_index[v];
  }
  m_index[v] = NOT_IN_SET;
}

template<typename T,T N> void integer_set<T,N>::erase(const integer_set& set)
{
  for(T v : set)
    erase(v);
}

template<typename T,T N> integer_set<T,N> integer_set<T,N>::union_(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2)
{
  if(set1.m_size <= set2.m_size)
  {
    integer_set out(set2);
    out.insert(set1);
    return out;
  }
  else
  {
    integer_set out(set1);
    out.insert(set2);
    return out;
  }
}

template<typename T,T N> integer_set<T,N> integer_set<T,N>::intersection(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2)
{
  integer_set out;
  if(set1.m_size <= set2.m_size)
  {
    for(T v : set1)
    {
      if(set2.contains(v))
        out.insert(v);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for(T v : set2)
    {
      if(set1.contains(v))
        out.insert(v);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::union_empty(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2)
{
  return set1.m_size == 0 && set2.m_size == 0;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::intersection_empty(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2)
{
  if(set1.m_size <= set2.m_size)
  {
    for(T v : set1)
    {
      if(set2.contains(v))
        return false;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for(T v : set2)
    {
      if(set1.contains(v))
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::min_size_to_search_index()
{
  // Bisection
  T min_size = 1;
  T max_size = N;
  T mid_size = (min_size+max_size)/2;
  do
  {
    if(get_probability(mid_size) >= 0.5)
      max_size = mid_size;
    else
      min_size = mid_size;
    mid_size = (min_size+max_size)/2;
  }
  while(mid_size != min_size);

  return max_size;
}

template<typename T,T N> double integer_set<T,N>::get_probability(T size)
{
  // Simplification of the hypergeometric distribution.
  // 1-hygepdf(0,N,size,size) =
  //     (N-size)!*(N-size)!
  // 1 - ___________________
  //      (N-size-size)!*N!
  double num = static_cast<double>(N-size);
  double den = static_cast<double>(N);
  double p = num/den;
  for(T i=1; i<size; ++i)
  {
    --num;
    --den;
    p *= num/den;
  }
  return 1.0-p;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// integer_set::iterator

template<typename T,T N> integer_set<T,N>::iterator::iterator()
  :m_element{nullptr}
{}

template<typename T,T N> integer_set<T,N>::iterator::iterator(const T* element)
  :m_element{element}
{}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator==(const iterator& it) const
{
  return m_element == it.m_element;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator!=(const iterator& it) const
{
  return m_element != it.m_element;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator<(const iterator& it) const
{
  return m_element < it.m_element;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator>(const iterator& it) const
{
  return m_element > it.m_element;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator<=(const iterator& it) const
{
  return m_element <= it.m_element;
}

template<typename T,T N> bool integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator>=(const iterator& it) const
{
  return m_element >= it.m_element;
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator*() const
{
  return *m_element;
}

template<typename T,T N> T integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator[](T i) const
{
  return m_element[i];
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator& integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator++()
{
  ++m_element;
  return *this;
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator++(int)
{
  iterator temp(*this);
  operator++();
  return temp;
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator& integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator--()
{
  --m_element;
  return *this;
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator--(int)
{
  iterator temp(*this);
  operator--();
  return temp;
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator+(T i) const
{
  return iterator(m_element+i);
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator-(T i) const
{
  return iterator(m_element-i);
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator& integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator+=(T i)
{
  m_element += i;
  return *this;
}

template<typename T,T N> typename integer_set<T,N>::iterator& integer_set<T,N>::iterator::operator-=(T i)
{
  m_element -= i;
  return *this;
}
```

### Edit:

I implemented this container to speed up a program that uses many set operations. This container gives me a speed up of two orders of magnitude compared to `std::unordered_set`.

These functions are nearly identical to `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`. Like `std::unordered_set`, iterators return the elements in no particular order.

```
integer_set();
integer_set(const integer_set& set);
integer_set& operator=(const integer_set& set);
bool operator==(const integer_set& set) const;
bool operator!=(const integer_set& set) const;
iterator begin() const;
iterator end() const;
T front() const;
T back() const;
iterator find(T v) const;
void clear();
bool empty() const;
T size() const;
void insert(T v);
void erase(T v);
```

These are convenience functions not provided by `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`:

```
// Same as insert(set.begin(),set.end())
void insert(const integer_set& set);
// Same as erase(set.begin,set.end())
void erase(const integer_set& set);
// Test if integer v is in set. Same as find(v) != end()
bool contains(T v) const;
// Smallest/largest integer in set.
T min() const;
T max() const;
// Random integer in set given a RNG e.g. std::mersenne_twister_engine
template<class URNG> T random(URNG& gen) const;
// Element of set. Same as *(begin()+i).
T operator[](T i) const;
// Lexicographical comparison
bool operator<=(const integer_set& set) const;
bool operator>=(const integer_set& set) const;
bool operator<(const integer_set& set) const;
bool operator>(const integer_set& set) const;
// Self Explanatory
integer_set union_(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2);
integer_set intersection(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2);
bool union_empty(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2);
bool intersection_empty(const integer_set& set1,const integer_set& set2);
```

Here is an example:

```
#include "integer_set.h"
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
  typedef integer_set<uint16_t,256> set256;

  set256 set1;
  set1.insert(144);
  set1.insert(255);
  set1.insert(0);
  assert(set1.find(0) != set1.end());
  assert(set1.contains(144));
  assert(set1.contains(255));
  set1.clear();
  assert(set1.begin() == set1.end());

  for(uint16_t i=30;i<100;i+=7)
    set1.insert(i);
  set1.insert(2);
  set1.insert(252);
  for(uint16_t i=121;i<240;i+=3)
    set1.insert(i);
  assert(set1.min() == 2);
  assert(set1.max() == 252);

  set256 set2;
  set2.insert(30);
  assert( set256::intersection(set1,set2).contains(30) );

  set2 = set1;
  for(uint16_t member : set2)
    set1.erase(member);
  assert(set1.empty());

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given by @galop1n is a good one, but since you asked for review, here is what could actually be improved in your code:

- Your class `iterator` is nothing but a wrapper which does exactly the same thing as `std::array<T, N>::iterator`. Therefore, you can simply write

  ```
  using iterator = typename std::array<T, N>::iterator;
  ```

  ...and delete your whole iterator implementation. The only things that are really important are the values passed to it by `begin` and `end`.
- It's not really important, but I would have kept my includes in alphbetical order so that I know exactly whether I have to look for an included header higher or lower in the list:

  ```
  #include <array>
  #include <bitset>
  #include <random>
  ```
- You obviously have a naming problem with `union_`. Since you are creating a `set` class, I would use `operator&` for intersection and `operator|` for union. While it is not recommended to overload operators when the meaning is not obvious, these operators are already commonly used for set operations (*e.g.* [`set` and `frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=frozenset#set.union) in Python's standard library). To improve consistency and usability, you can also implement `operator&=` and `operator|=`; users will expect them to be available if you already provide `operator&` and `operator|`.
- We already tackled the problem for `union_` and `intersection` by making them operators, but I don't really like the fact that `union_empty` and `intersection_empty` are `static` functions. The need not be `static` since the only `private` member they access is `m_size`, and you can get this member by calling the method `size`. I would have made them free functions instead.
- I don't believe that checking for `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` in the static assertions is useful since `is_unsigned` is only `true` for unsigned integer types. It is probably redundant.
- In the method `random`, you pass the random number generator by reference. The idiomatic way to pass a random number generator (*e.g.* `std::shuffle` or `std::sample`) is to pass it by universal reference and to `std::forward` it to the following function:

  ```
  template<typename T,T N>
  template<class URNG>
  T integer_set<T,N>::random(URNG&& gen) const
  {
      return m_list[std::uniform_int_distribution<T>(0,m_size-1)(std::forward<URNG>(gen))];
  }
  ```
- This line:

  ```
  template<typename T,T N> constexpr T integer_set<T,N>::NOT_IN_SET;
  ```

  Since you already initialized `NOT_IN_SET` directly in the class declaration, this line is useless. You should remove it.

Answer (score 5):

You should learn about [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

It has almost everything you wants already with far less data storage. Encapsulate it inside your class to keep track of `min`, `max` and `count` in O(1) and write a custom iterator to list only the raised bits.

But according to your real usage, it may be not even needed and a mere `std::bitset` will be enough.

Below is your test case translated with a bitset:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout <<  std::boolalpha;
  //typedef integer_set<uint16_t,256> set256;
  using set256 = std::bitset<256>;
  std::cout << "byte count for 256 bits : " << sizeof(set256) << '\n';

  set256 set1;
  set1.set(144);
  set1.set(255);
  set1.set(0);

  std::cout << "test separate bits : ";
  std::cout << set1.test(0) << " ";
  std::cout << set1.test(144) << " ";
  std::cout << set1.test(255) << "\n";

  std::cout << "count before after reset : ";
  std::cout << set1.count() << " ";
  set1.reset();
  std::cout << set1.count() << "\n";

  for(uint16_t i=30;i<100;i+=7)
    set1.set(i);
  set1.set(2);
  set1.set(252);
  for(uint16_t i=121;i<240;i+=3)
    set1.set(i);

  set256 set2;
  set2.set(30);

  auto inter = set1&set2;
  std::cout << "test over an intersection : " << inter.test(30) << "\n";

  set2 = set1;
  set1 &= ~set2;
  std::cout << "a complicated way to clear a bit set by anding a flipped copy : " << set1.count() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```